# nSequence win OP_CSV in child tx must be equal to nSeq parent tx?

Tags: bitcoind, script, raw-transaction

When I create OP_CSV  transaction I need to set nSequence to the same number (in blocks) 
e.g.

```
3 OP_CHECKSEQUENCEVERIFY
nSequence = 3
```

But when I trying to spend this tx (after 3 blocks confirmation) I have to generate transaction with the same nSequence as parent.

Otherwise I'm getting error (when I'm trying to spend with different nSequence)

```
non-mandatory-script-verify-flag (Locktime requirement not satisfied) (code 64)
```

But I wont set the nSequence to child transaction, because, in this case, I can't spend immediately child transaction.

Do I need to set some flag or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your misconception is that the nSequence value must be set on the transaction that *creates* the CSV output.

This is not required. All that's needed is setting it on the spending transaction's input which spends it. This will indirectly require that output to have a certain age when it is being spent.